# Discord.py: Obtaining user ID from username of member who doesn't share a guild with the bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send a direct message using a bot to a person who doesn't share a common guild with the bot. For this I need to have the user ID of the person but in my use case I'm only having access to the username + discriminator. Is there a way to obtain the ID using the username?

Something like..

---

```
user_id = client.fetch_user("bob#0000")
user=await client.get_user_info(user_id)
await client.send_message(user, "message")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible for a bot to get a user's ID by only their name and discriminator if it does not share any common guilds. The [API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user) does not have any endpoints to do so at the time of writing. [The `UserConverter` in discord.py can only convert by name and discriminator if the user appears in the cache](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/64744a4938f101af7dbeb517a5b81b99837e89fb/discord/ext/commands/converter.py#L310-L325), which is usually not the case if there are no common guilds.